# Error Getting libframe to compile

Tags: linux, gcc

I am trying to compile libframe. When I do, I receive the following messages.

```
BaseException.cpp: In constructor 'BaseException::BaseException()':
BaseException.cpp:30:33: error: 'strcpy' was not declared in this scope
BaseException.cpp: In constructor 'BaseException::BaseException(const char*)':
BaseException.cpp:35:31: error: 'strncpy' was not declared in this scope
BaseException.cpp: In constructor 'BaseException::BaseException(std::string&)':
BaseException.cpp:41:39: error: 'strncpy' was not declared in this scope
BaseException.cpp: In static member function 'static BaseException BaseException::factory(const char*, ...)':
BaseException.cpp:49:31: error: 'memset' was not declared in this scope
make[1]: *** [BaseException.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/alanc/media_man/libframe/libframe-1.0.0/src'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

I am having trouble finding any information about this program.

[libframe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libframe/)

Thanks.

Comment: I am looking into similar libraries.  This one is pretty old and not maintained ( As most of them seem to be unless they are system specific ).  Assuming your are attempting to use this lib for portability; have you found any other alternatives or been able to work with this one yet?